# RouteConfig - IIS10+C# - Redirect Old Links

Tags: c#, http-status-code-301, friendly-url, iis-10

Good evening,
I'm pretty new on **C#** and **IIS**, and I am trying to figure it out about **FriendlyUrls**.

I guess I'm doing good but, I have an issue.

Let's say that today my site has all the pages in the /Pages folder so that an URL would be:

```
https://www.foo.xyz/Pages/my-dog.aspx
```

With the default FriendlyUrls installation, a user using that link, would see this in his browser:

```
https://www.foo.xyz/Pages/my-dog
```

And that is really ok, but not enough yet.

With this piece of code:

```
 routes.MapPageRoute("FirstLevel", "{file}", "~/Pages/{file}.aspx");
```

Every new url www.foo.xyz/my-dog would point to the same file /Pages/my-dog.aspx.

So, I will keep on using the previous files.

But now... I would like to to tell a browser or a spider that all previous links made like /Pages/foo.aspx are permamently moved (301) to the brand new link.
Is it possible to do that via code? Or do I need to use the IIS url rewrite module and keep the business logic in the web.config file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that with URL rewrite rule.

```
 <rule name="rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/Pages/(.*)\.aspx" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="Pages/{C:1}" />
                </rule>
```